# Why MATLAB is slow in this case compared to Mathematica

Tags: performance, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I have this code in Mathematica:

```
n = 5;
k1[x_, t_] := t^2;
k[m_, n_] := (1/(m!*n!)*D[k1[x, t], {t, n}, {x, m}]) /. {x -> 0, t -> 0};
kmn = Table[k[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
kmn // MatrixForm
```

which get executed in just **0.03** seconds.

The following is the equivalent code I ended up in MATLAB:

```
syms t x;
n=5;
k1 = @(x,t) t^2;
kmn=zeros(n+1);
for i=0:n
    for j=0:n
        dift=subs(diff(k1,t,j),t,0);
        kmn(i+1,j+1)=(1/(factorial(j)*factorial(i)))*subs(diff(dift,x,i),x,0);
    end
end
kmn
```

But it executes in **4.970502** seconds.

What's wrong with my MATLAB code? Or, is this the fault of MATLAB? I want to reduce the processing time as much as possible.

Comment: Running the code the first time takes 3 seconds, any further execution is much faster (1/4s). Did you run the code multiple times? Probably the code is slow the first time because the toolbox has to be initialised or similar stuff.

Comment: @Daniel Yes I did. Any ideas on perhaps code optimization? or anything else?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I'm getting the same situation as Daniel.  Using `subs`, `syms` etc. on the first invocation has some initial set up that takes a couple of seconds to complete.  Once that happens, when I re-run the above code multiple times. It's pretty fast.  When running `timeit` on the above code, I get `0.378` seconds.  If you want to optimize your code further, consider abandoning symbolic math and using numerical equivalents instead.  Judging from your posts, you're transitioning over from Mathematica, so that may be difficult.  MATLAB is meant to be used for numerical analysis.

Comment: for this example its likely faster if you switch the order of differentiation. really id suggest a more complicated function for testing performance

Answer (score 1):

Trying to come up with "equivalent" code is always fraught with hazards. Mathematica and Matlab's symbolic math are quite different in their philosophies and implementations.

In the case of your proposed Matlab code, the first thing you want to try to do is remove the double `for` loop. Then try to vectorize and operations and reuse previous results. If possible, perform calculation numerically, rather than symbolically as long as you know the result will be exact (e.g., `factorial` for small integers). Here's an attempt to do some of these things:

```
syms t x;
n = 5;
k1 = @(x,t) t^2;
kmn = zeros(n+1);
j = 0:n;

dift = zeros(1,n+1,'sym');
for i = j
    dift(i+1) = subs(diff(k1,t,i),t,0);
end

fj = factorial(j);
for i = j
     kmn(i+1,:) = subs(diff(dift,x,i),x,0)./(fj.*fj(i+1));
end
kmn
```

The code could be further optimized to remove needless differentiation and substitution in the case when `k1` isn't a function of `x`. And if `k1` is a is meant to be a polynomial, there are many possibilities.

However, it'd be much better if we knew what underlying algorithm/equation you were trying to implement as there might be built-in functions that directly calculate some or all of the things you want.